# I can't get localization to work in cakephp 2.3

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

Localization on my website was working until one day, my website went down. The host did some changes and after that, my website is in english.
I set the default language to French but everything is in english.
If I display the language

```
echo Configure::read('Config.language');
```

The result is "fre"
I have set `Configure::write('Config.language', 'fre');` in bootstrap.php
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the host what changes they did.

Comment: they disabled 'ini_set' but now I changed the host and same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.3 the lang code for french was changed from `fre` to `fra` as mentioned in the [migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-3-migration-guide.html#l10n).